# ICEPlot in python for cervical cancer using PDPBox

Tags: data-visualization

I was going through [Individual Conditional Expectation (ICE)](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/ice.html) and trying to re-create the plots using python. What I did is to make a model, and pass it as parameter to the [PDPBox](https://github.com/SauceCat/PDPbox) library function. But it did not create the expected result.

The first image shows the plot from the book, showing chances increases at 40 s, and the second one shows the one from PDPBox where the chance changes at 20 s.

What am I missing?

[image]

[image]